# Underground electrical box?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor, landscaping

The picture shows the spot in my front yard where an outlet used to be. There is a fourth wire not visible in the picture. We have since brought the  grade down about two feet and it no longer makes sense for us to have an outlet there as it would be in the middle of a patio-type space. The space will mostly likely have a gravel covering. The wires feed outdoor street lights which cannot be sacrificed.

I don't suppose I could make the junction underground - or can I?

Assuming I can't, what are some of the alternative solutions that are not a complete eyesore?

[image]

Update: for all the good answers I received, I cannot find a device for making a waterproof 4-way underground splice.

Comment: If you can't do 4 cables all at once, how about a series of splices, each having fewer cables involved?

Comment: 4 can be done large tube and crimp or underground wire nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have junctions underground. If that cable is underground rated it can be done without a box if buried to code. A junction box could be located and underground splices can be used the big deal is a splice that seals inexpensive kits are under 20$ 3-4 wires the terminal block and the heat shrink , easy to do and code compliant big box stores usually have the kits.

Comment: Didn't know about these kits. However, I have four cables (the fourth one is not shown). I'll check if 4-cable (8 conductors + 4 grounds) exist.

Comment: Yes they are called splice / tap kits , resin splice kits, and gel filled splice kits on top of underground wire nuts.   . wire crimps then encased in a gel pack easy to use, resin tubes you put your crimped connector in the tube and fill with the sealing resin  Lots of possibilities you may be most comfortable with ideal underground wire connectors (wire nuts)

Comment: Yep - those splice kits usually are also good for total underwater applications also (pump wiring at the bottom of a drilled well, for example).

Comment: @j... yes these kits are usually rated for submerged use also. At first I did not think the gel packs would work but when you close the cover the gel becomes 1 mass around the wire , I like the heat shrink ones for simple splices , the tubes take longest because after you ring crimp the wires put them in the tube you have to wait for the resin to set up, the blue gray wire nuts for underground can handle 4 or 5 #10 if memory serves.

Comment: Have I overcomplicated things? Why not simply use the Aqua/Red gel-filled wire nuts?

Comment: I could not tell the wire size,  I did list the wire nuts. With 4 wires I don’t think red will be large enough the under ground rating is not as many wires as the standard, blue gray 3 number 12 minimum I don’t have them on hand as I crimp and use epoxy tubes (more common with larger sizes).

Answer (score 8):

The other option is to put in a "hand-hole" so called - you've walked over them, some you have driven over (those ones cost more). They are (generally) like a box missing the bottom, with a removable top, and you set them over the conduits so the top is flush with the ground surface. You still need a waterproof splice method, but if you ever need to access it again it's a whole lot easier to find. The drive-over ones are usually made of concrete, the others are commonly plastic.

If you have "brought the grade down two feet" I'm wondering how much cover your conduit (or is that water pipe being used as conduit?) now has.